# splitting string and adding the output string and creating a hashmap out of it in scala

Tags: scala, parsing, split, hashmap

I have a csv file with two columns like this:

```
column1                             column2
sachin@@@tendulkar@@@Ganguly       cricket@@@India@@@players
```

I want to convert it to a hash map which would be like this:

```
sachin-> "cricket, India, players"
tendulkar-> "cricket, India, players"
Ganguly-> "cricket, India, players"
```

cricket, India, players this should be a one string. How can I get it done in scala?
This is what I have done so far

```
val csv = sc.textFile("/tag/players.csv")  
val headerAndRows = csv.map(line => line.split(",").map(_.trim))
val header = headerAndRows.first()  
val synonyms = csv.map(_.split(",")).map( p=>(p(1))  // for column1
val targettag = csv.map(_.split(",")).map(p=>p(2))   // for column2
val splitsyno = synonyms.map(x => x.split("@@@"))
val splittarget = targettag.map(x=>x.split("@@@"))
```

I want to know how to proceed forward to create the desired hashmap?

Comment: What problem do you have? You unable to read file? Unable to parse it as CSV? Unable to split strings? Unable to combine them with separator you want? Unable to put them in `Map`?

Comment: It is comma seperated. 
val targettag = csv.map(_.split(",")).map(p=>p(2)) 
val splitsyno = targettag.map(x => x.split("@@@"))
I have split the strings but am not able to create desired hashmap

Comment: Put your code in your question and specify what part is causing the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That code works for a single line. After that you can merge all lines if you want to. I've hardcoded the provided row.

First it splits the data into a tuple.
Step2 is replacing the '@@@' of column2 with ','.
Step3 is splitting 'column1' at '@@@' and map it to a tuple as element of a Map and then convert it to a map.

You can quite optimize the solution.

```
val data = "sachin@@@tendulkar@@@Ganguly, cricket@@@India@@@players"

val (c1:String, c2:String) = data.split(",") match {
  case Array(a, b) => (a,b)
}
val c2s = c2.replace("@@@", ",")
val xx = c1.split("@@@").map(_ -> c2s).toMap

// Just to validate the ouput
xx.foreach(f => println(f._1 + "->" + f._2))
```

Comment: Hey, I have to read this csv to sparkrdd first. For which I did:
val data = csv.map(_.split(",")).map( p=>p(1)+"###"+p(2))
### because there commas inside column entries itself. now when I am doing this val (c1:String, c2:String) = data.take(totalcountof1).map(x=>x.split("###")) match {case Array(a, b) => (a,b)})  this throws an error: found   : String
 required: Array[String]

Comment: Look at your parenthesis. You are applying the match to the result of take(). You should apply it to x.split('###') match {...})

Comment: Thanks for your response. But I am getting a new error as :
found   : (T1, T2)
 required: Array[(String, String)]

Comment: val (c1:String, c2:String) = data.take(totalcountof1).map(x=>x.split("###") match {case Array(a, b) => (a,b)})  this should work....

Comment: with the exact above command the error is this: error: constructor cannot be instantiated to expected type;
 found   : (T1, T2)
 required: Array[(String, String)]

Comment: Hey, I am still stuck at this. What is the way out?

Comment: I dont know what to tell you. As far AS you are variing the code and you dont know how the typing works, its quite hard to to tell. I need the full error log and code otherwise I don't know what's happening before and after. I provided an approach that solved your stated problem. But now it's just applying the stuff to your codebase and as far as your example shows your usecase it should be copy n paste

Comment: these are the lines:
val csv = sc.textFile("/tag/players.csv")   /// read csv ///
val data = csv.map(_.split(",")).map( p=>p(1)+"###"+p(2))   /// this line brings data in the format as you have for val data except with ### in between ///
val (c1:String, c2:String) = data.take(100).map(x=>x.split("###") match {case Array(a, b) => (a,b)})   /// throws the error as mentioned above

Comment: Try it yourself. Step 1 instead of saying val (c1...,c2...) = data.... Do: val x = data ... Check the type and I guess it will be (Any, Any) because the compiler can't interfere the type. Which ide are u using?

Comment: Hey, this works. But then what should I do for this?val c2s = c2.replace("@@@", ",")
val xx = c1.split("@@@").map(_ -> c2s).toMap

Comment: val data = csv.map(_.split(",")).map( p=>p(1)+"###"+p(2))
     val (x) = data.take(20).map(x=>x.split("###") match {case Array(a, b) => (a,b)}) 
     var A:Map[String,String] = Map()
     for (z<-x){A = A ++ (z._1.split("@@@").map(_ ->z._2.replace("@@@",",") ).toMap)}
     A.foreach(f => println(f._1 + "->" + f._2))
This is done now. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

I would do the following (note, I'm skipping over mapping a row of a csv to extract `column1` and `column2`):

```
val synonyms = List("sachin", "tendulkar", "Ganguly")
val target = "cricket@@@India@@@players".replaceAll("@@@", ", ")
for(s <- synonyms) yield s -> target
```

Answer (score 0):

This code works but is very un"functional"

```
import scala.collection.mutable.Map

object parseData {
  val inputSource = io.Source.fromFile("<input-file>")
  val dataMap = Map.empty[String, String]
  for (line <- inputSource.getLines.drop(1)) {
    val keysAndValues = line.split(" +")
    val keys = keysAndValues(0).split("@@@")
    val values = keysAndValues(1).split("@@@").mkString(", ")
    for (k <- keys) {
      dataMap += (k -> values)
    }
  }
  inputSource.close
}
```

We can probably idiomize a bunch of things. But is a good enough start. The `drop(1)` is to not include `column1` and `column2` in the `dataMap`.

Output:

```
Map(tendulkar -> cricket, India, players, Ganguly -> cricket, India, players, sachin -> cricket, India, players)
```